# Why is "success" spelled with double -S?

Tags: etymology, orthography, latin

What is the function of the double *s* at the end of the word, success?

Answer (score 5):

It makes it clear that it's /səkˈsɛs/ rather than /səkˈsis/ or /sʌks/.

History bit:

Originally, it made the next syllable start with an /s/ sound, even though the last syllable doesn't exist any more.

The Latin verb *succedere* (from which we get *succeed*) had a past participal *successo* and some past historic forms had a similar double-S (*successi*, *successe*, *successero*, *succedessi*) while some imperfect forms had a double-S but not also the D (*succedessi*, *succedesse*, *succedessimo*, *succedeste*, *succedessero*).

The Latin noun *successus* and it's various forms (*successum*, *successibus* and so on) came from that verb.

In these Latin words, that these two Ss are both pronounced, one ending a syllable and the next beginning the next syllable.

This became an English word that was sometimes spelt *success* and sometimes *successe*. Even in the second spelling, the final *-se* wasn't pronounced because English had already stopped pronouncing terminal *-e* in most cases.

The *successe* spelling died out around the late 17th Century or so, leaving us with just *success*.

Still, that it doesn't serve the role it did in Latin doesn't make it solely a historical legacy, as I said at the beginning, it's clear that *success* is pronounced /səkˈsɛs/ but it wouldn't be as clear rather than whether *succes* was pronounced /səkˈsis/, /səkˈsis/ ("suckies") or /sʌks/ ("sucks").

Comment: It might be useful to illustrate how the word, *successum* and *successibus* are divided into syllables: suc.ces.sum and suc.ces.si.bus

Comment: I don’t see how _succes_ could be /sʌks/ in any kind of ‘regular’ (as much as that’s possible) way in English. I would presume _succes_ should be pronounced /ˈsʌksɨs/ (‘sucks-es’) and be the plural form of a noun (or the third singular present of a verb) pronounced /sʌks/, however that might be spelt.

Comment: Also, those forms of _succedō_ you give that have both the _d_ and the _ss_ do not exist in Latin, as far as I know. Not in Classical Latin, at least—are you giving forms from late Vulgar Latin? (They look more like Italian imperfective subjunctives to me.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet late Latin AFAIK.